# GWT Button State Problem

Tags: gwt, button, usability

I have a button in a GWT application that is initially disabled, but over the course of the application may become enabled.

There is a bizarre behavior occurring, where if somebody attempts to click the button before it is enabled, it is surrounded by a dotted outline, and then when it becomes enabled, unless you click outside of the button to remove the outline, it acts as though it is still disabled.

This seems like a bug to me, but anybody experience this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems as though if I call button.setFocus(false) after enabling it, this problem does not occur.  Still seems like a bug to me!